# Configuring an LED project

Tags: power-supply, led

I’m trying to build a world map comprised of about 130 warm 3mm 3200K LEDs. The LEDs should be able to be swapped out at will with green or blue LEDs. How do I design a circuit that would achieve this? Pretty new to EE so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

3mm LEDs are typically a bit smaller in lead dimension than most 2.54mm pitch connectors (0.025" square pins), but some female connectors may fit acceptably well- in which case you could trim the leads of the LEDs and pliug them into the sockets, which in turn could be mounted on a PCB of your own design or perf board. If you want to go that route try a few first since it is off label usage.

You could also use the Chinese SMT addressable LEDs which contain a PWM driver and four LED colors- red, green, blue, and warm white. They are available in 5mm square SMT packages and can be controlled from something like an Arduino.

In either case a 5V power supply or simlar is required. The addressable LEDs need a bypass capacitor each, and the socket LEDs require a series resistor each.

If you go the 3mm route, you can try to buy LEDs with similar brightness- buy some may appear much brighter or dimmer mostly because of differences in the LEDs themselves. The addressable ones can be set to a range of brightnesses for each LED.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not controlling each of these leds, then use quick connectors or screw terminals so you can replace them as needed. As the forward voltage of the white AND blue are similar you shouldn't need to change a resistor for then, but green is likely to be lower. So you can change the led and resistor at the same time. So the simplest circuit is a 5V 3 Amp power supply, and a resistor for each led.

A modern approach would be to use addressable rgb leds with a controller. Then you don't need to change the led, just command it to go from white to green or blue. Of course this adds complexity, as you also need to figure out how to control them (Bluetooth to a phone or wifi to any computer).